# Нужна помощь с регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Html выглядит так:

```
<h4>Плюсы</h4><ul>  <li>Доступная цена.</li>    <li>Есть во многих магазинах.</li>  <li>Практичный дизайн.</li>     <li>Хорошо удаляет волосы.</li>     <li>Хватает на несколько процедур.</li>     <li>В комплект входит 5 бритв.</li>     <li>Острые лезвия.</li></ul>
<h4>Минусы</h4>Не справляется с жесткой щетиной.<h3>Arko Men System3</h3блабалб бал бла бла бла
<h4>Плюсы</h4><ul>  <li>Недорогие.</li>     <li>Некоторые пользователи применяют их для нескольких процедур. При этом лезвия сохраняют свою остроту.</li>   <li>Не вызывают раздражение.</li>   <li>Плавающая головка.</li>     <li>Низкая стоимость.</li>  <li>В набор входит 4 станка.</li></ul>
<h4>Минусы</h4> <ul><li>Плавающая головка.</li>     <li>Низкая стоимость.</li>  <li>В набор входит 4 станка.</li> </ul>
```

Нужно регулярным выражением вытащить списки - все что между

```
<ul></ul>
```

под заголовками Плюсы и Минусы. При этом, если списка под заголовком нет - то совпадать не должно.

Моё выражение выглядит так:

```
<h4[^>]*>Плюсы</h4>([^<]*?)(<ul>.*?</ul>)[^<]*?<h4>Минусы</h4>[^<]+(<ul>.*?</ul>)
```

Но оно работает некорректно - под первым заголовком "Минусы" нет списка и оно захватывает весь текст до второго заголовка "Минусы", в котором список есть. Хотя, как я представляю, на теге h3 должно стопориться.

Как грамотно составить?

Comment: Добавьте какие данные регулярка должна вытащить

Comment: @Олег А парсер html от языка нельзя применить?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это сложнее. Задача поменять код в куче записей вордпресс. Сейчас пытаюсь через регулярку в дампе базы поменять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот [так](https://regex101.com/r/UTBUah/2)

```
(<h4\b[^>]*>(.*?)</h4>)[\s]?(<ul\b[^>]*>(.*?)</ul>)
```

> Если между заголовками нет перевода строки, то не работает:
>   regex101.com/r/jnZtRX/1

```
(<h4>)(Плюсы|Минусы)(</h4>)[\s]*(<ul>)+[\s]*((<li>[\w\s.]*</li>)|[\s]*)+(</ul>)+
```

[Проверка](https://regex101.com/r/QdfiV9/1/)

Comment: Если между заголовками нет перевода строки, то не работает: https://regex101.com/r/jnZtRX/1/

Comment: @Олег: Не подходит вам последнее решение?

Comment: подходит, спасибо